# Evitar repetidos en Matriz

Tags: c#

Edito mi pregunta anterior, tengo este código:

Métodos:

```
class Program
{
    static void nuevo(int[] lista, int cantidad, ref int tope)
    {
        lista[tope] = cantidad;
        tope++;
    }

    static void jugada (int[,]m, int napostante) 
    {
        for(int col=0; col<m.GetLength(1);col++)
        {
            m[napostante,col] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        }
    }
}
```

Y este en el main:

```
case 1:

    if (tope < nombre.Length)
    {

        Console.Write("Nombre: ");
        nombre[tope] = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Write("Jugada : ");
        cargarjugada(matriz, tope);
        agregar(vector, cantidad, ref tope);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("No hay mas cupos");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    break;
```

como podría controlar que los números ingresados no se repitan y no se ingresen letras en lugar de numeros?, esto mismo lo puedo aplicar luego para un `Random`. Es programación estructurada y puedo utilizar comparadores, variables, matrices y arrays.

Comment: Vete metiendo los numeros en un `Set`, que es una estructura de datos que no permite repeticiones. Cuando saques un valor random, intentas meterlo en el set y si no se puede sacas otro valor random. Intentalo y si tienes dudas concretas preguntalas aqui. Un saludo

Comment: Muchas gracias estimado por tu pronta respuesta, pero como el "set" aun no lo hemos dado, (recién inicio la carrera), no puedo utilizarlo, tendría que ser un control dentro del for, pienso

Comment: Bueno, pues un array donde vas guardando los valores sacados y recorrerlo cada vez que sacas un numero.. edita la pregunta para mejorar  la explicacion de lo que has intentado. Y no veo donde modificas la variable `seguir` que siempre es `true`

Comment: seguir esta en otro punto del programa, ya que es un menu con varios items, y salir se vuelve false en el case 7

Comment: Fijate que en este caso, podes suscribir el problema a algo mucho mas reducido, y preguntar por tu duda particular sin todo el codigo que pusiste. Tu duda es como evitar repetir numeros que salen de un random, que por logica se van a repetir. Y como es tarea para la facultad, tenes un monton de restricciones que nunca aclaraste, y van a haber montones de respuestas sin saber eso. Por favor aclara la pregunta para que podamos contestar basados en tu problema en particualr

Comment: No es tarea de facultad, de hecho es un curso de programador net, el cual recién inicio, y colocó el resto del código para que se entienda un poco más el problema

Answer (score 1):

Si guardas los valores obtenidos en un array puedes hacer un while para seguir sacando números mientras el array contenga ese numero. Algo parecido a esto:

```
using System.Linq;

public class Loteria
{
    public void GuardarNumeros()
    {
        int[] numeros = new int[5];
        for (int i = 0; i < numeros.Length; i++)
        {
            int numero = ObtenerNumeroAleatorio();
            while (numeros.Contains(numero))
            {
                numero = ObtenerNumeroAleatorio();
            }
            numeros[i] = numero;
        }
    }
}
```

<strike>También no encuentro en tu código donde haces el random para obtener el número aleatoriamente.</strike>

El problema viene principalmente en tu uso del Random(), explicación en inglés [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767999/random-number-generator-only-generating-one-random-number). Al llamar al constructor del Random() utiliza información del ordenador, el reloj, para generar aleatoriamente los números, una especie de semilla. Como el proceso es tan rápido, en las 5 vueltas estás utilizando la misma semilla y por tanto el número aleatorio es siempre el mismo.

Si sacar el constructor fuera del for, la probabilidad de obtener el mismo número aleatorio será menor.

```
Random numeros = new Random();
for (int sorpresa = 0; sorpresa <= 4; sorpresa++)
{
    Console.Write(numeros.Next(0, 48));
}
```

---

Has cambiado totalmente la pregunta con tu última modificación:

En primer lugar para comprobar que no se puedan introducir letras puedes usar la función TryParse. La función TryParse existe en todos los tipos de variable y pasándole una cadena, devuelve verdadero o falso si se pudo convertir, y en caso de convertirse, saca de la función la variable transformada. Lo que necesitarías hacer es algo así:

```
string valorIntroducido = LeerValor();
int valorComoEntero;
while (!int.TryParse(valorIntroducido, out valorComoEntero))
{
    valorIntroducido = LeerValor();
}
```

Para evitar repeticiones en la matriz tendrías que hacer lo que expliqué antes, solo que en lugar de Contains, tendrías que recorrer cada índice del array preguntando si ese índice del array es igual al valor introducido. Tendrías que usar una variable de control puesta a "false". Si algun índice del aray contiene ese valor, pones la variable a "true". Una vez terminado de recorrer el array, si la variable está a "true", vuelve a sacar otro número, si está a "false", lo insertas porque no existía en la matriz.

Comment: Perdon, habia colgado el case 1, el random esta en el 2, ya lo edite, `contains` lo puedo sustituir por `!=` ? ya que `contains` no lo he visto aun, eso seria un metodo aparte no? va de la mano con el case 1

Comment: no no podes reemplazar contains directamente por !=, necesitas recorrer todo el vector y revisar caso por caso.

Comment: El contains lo puse por facilitar un poco. Si no lo has dado tendrías que recorrer todos los números posibles. De todas formas he aclarado un poco en mi respuesta el uso del Random y el porqué creo que te sale siempre el mismo número.

Comment: con el edit se aclara el problema y es "parte" de la solucion. Igual por mas que agregue una semilla, sigue existiendo la posibilidad que ante un espacio tan resumido de numeros, se le repitan.

Comment: Sí, la respuesta sería una solución de ambas partes, arreglar la parte del Random() para que la repetición de los números sea menos probable al lanzarse tan rápido y la comprobación de si ya se insertó o no para volver a sacar otro.

Comment: @aenon83 como podria modificar mi codigo para introducir la variable booleana?

Comment: @Alejandro Pues sería dentro del 'for'. En primer lugar realiza un 'while' hasta que se haya insertado un número y justo después declara una variable a 'false'. Después recorre con un 'for' cada elemento del array comparandolo con lo que leiste desde teclado. Si coincide, pon esa variable a true y lanza un break para no seguir recorriendo el array. Una vez terminado de recorrer, si la variable está a false, la insertas en el array.

Comment: No puedo darme cuenta en el método donde hacerlo